# WMS GetFeatureInfo not working

Tags: qgis, wms, getfeatureinfo, qgis-server

I created a WMS in a QGIS project and serve it with QGIS Server.

When I click on a feature on the WMS map, no attribute information is displayed.
I guess, the attributes are not exposed to the WMS but I do not know how to do this.

What settings are needed to expose attributes in QGIS to a WMS?

Comment: In layer properties > fields, you need to select all the attributes that you want to be queryable by WMS and or WFS